# How to get all replaceable variables from string? - Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string

"Hi `{{colums}}`, where is my `{{toy}}`. If it is with you kindly submit to `{{name}}`".

From this we should get all the strings bounded in {{}} as array

Ex: `['{{columns}}', '{{toy}}', '{{name}}']`

Kindly help here

Comment: which language? This is angular format, not vanilla format.

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? ```let x = "Hi {{colums}}, where is my {{toy}}. If it is with you kindly submit to {{name}}"; console.log(x.match(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g).map(x => '{{' + x + '}}'));```

Comment: Hi @AndrewHalpern, sorry, my question was wrong. Modified the description now. Here I need the strings as array as it is in the the sentense

Comment: That looks like `handlebars` format. https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#what-is-handlebars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expresion to parse the string:

```
let text = "Hi {{colums}}, where is my {{toy}}. If it is with you kindly submit to {{name}}";

let result = text.match(/({{[\w-_]*\}\}*)/gm)

// result = ["{{colums}}", "{{toy}}", "{{name}}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.match(/\{\{.*?\}\}/g)
```

This is working correctly.